# Disable jCenter repository in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, jcenter

In my Gradle project, I use a custom Maven repository to download the dependencies I need:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.my-company.com/'
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.my-company.com/'
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed that on our Jenkins, each build takes a couple more minutes to complete than on my computer.
With the help of the debug flag (`./gradlew --debug --refresh-dependencies  clean :app:assembleDebug | grep jcenter`), I noticed that each dependency is looked for in jCenter, even though I removed it from the `repositories` blocks:

```
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor] Constructing external resource: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid/maven-metadata.xml
```

As our Jenkins has no access to external network, those requests timeout and increase the overall build time.
Is there something to do to completely disable jCenter (or any other not explicitly defined repositories) repository in Gradle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked the question on Gradle's GitHub repository ([issue 10376](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/10376)).
The issue is not directly coming from my Gradle configuration, but a plugin that added the `jCenter` repository itself.

To find the plugin adding the repository, I created an `init.gradle` script like so:

```
allprojects {
    repositories.all {
        if (url.host == 'jcenter.bintray.com') {
            new Throwable('jcenter repository was just added').printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

And ran `./gradlew --init-script init.gradle help`. In the printed stacktrace I could find the plugin causing the issue, in my case `at io.realm.gradle.Realm.apply(Realm.groovy:75)`.